Integral of first and second normal derivative of $1/r$
Problem: 
I want to numerically compute the deceiptively simple looking surface integral of the second directional derivative of the source function $1/r$, namely $\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla (\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla (1/r))$ on a triangle, where $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal vector and the source is at the barycenter ($v_1$) of some triangle as shown in the next figure:

The fields of the functions  $f=1/r$ and its first and second normal derivatives, where $r$ is the distance between the source point and point on the surface look like this (side view, $n=[0, 1]$):

I understand that
$$\iint_S 1/r \ ds \neq 0$$
$$\iint_S \mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla (1/r) \ ds = 0$$
and I think (this is the integral I am interested in) it holds true that:
$$\iint_S \mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla (\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla (1/r)) \ ds \neq 0$$
Question: 
The integral is singular and only converges slowly when applying Duffy and Gauss quadrature - What are alternative ways to numerically compute this integral on the triangle (for example applying some vector calculus)?

Isn't Stokes' integral equality meant for the integral over the curl of some field? (I do not see the curl, so it's unclear what you are doing here in Stokes' name...  Is there another kind of Stokes equality that you are referring to?)

Sorry, I should have written this more clearly - I meant to refer to the Divergence theorem which is, as far is I understand, a special case of the Stokes theorem.

Then you perhaps should edit the question and explicitly state which function you are taking the divergence of. And in how many dimensions you want to apply the theorem. (Of course adding all those missing steps may already resolve the puzzle , which would be a pity...)

Thank you for your input - I edited the question and removed my (apparently faulty) approach and instead ask for ideas on how to approach this integral problem.

The regularization of the singularity at the point source seems more like a physics problem, no mathematical theorem can remove it, so you have to change the point source to something else! After that, the finite part of the integral can probably best be computed analytically, as I explain in the added answer (although it leads to a long expression for the total result so you still need a symbolic solver like https://www.wolfram.com/engine/ ).

Short answer: The integrand evaluates to exactly $-1/r^3$ on the triangle, so it is divergent at the barycenter and the answer is $-\infty$. If whatever method you use gives a finite value, then that's just accidental (and wrong!)
Long answer: We can try to regularize the integral by somehow subtracting the infinite part.
It turns out that the integral can then be done analytically.
By changing coordinates using rotations and translations (which leave the vector expression invariant) we can get this situation:

where the barycenter is now in the origin, the triangle is in the $xy$-plane, and the side $AB$ of the triangle is parallel to the $x$-axis.
To have the barycenter at $(0,0,0)$, the corners will then be given by three parameters $x_1,x_2, h$, as:
$$\begin{align}
\vec A&=(x_1,\ h,\ 0)  \\
\vec B&=(x_2,\ h,\ 0)  \\
\vec C&=(-x_1\!-x_2, -2h,\ 0)  \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
The normal $\bf n$ is then in the $z$-direction, so in these coordinates the operator
${\bf n} \cdot {\bf \nabla}$ becomes just $d/dz$. The integral we have to compute is:
$$
\int\limits_\text{T} \! \! d^2 r \ \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\, \frac1r
= 
\int\limits_\text{T} \! \! d^2 r \ \frac{3z^2-r^2}{r^5}
= 
\int\limits_\text{T} \! \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3}
= 
I_0+\int\limits_\text{T\S} \! \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3}
 $$
where the integral over the triangle T is only in the $xy$-plane so the term $3z^2$ in the numerator vanishes. The integral is non-convergent at the source in the origin, so we must regularize it, e.g. by omitting a circular region "S" in the center, as indicated in the drawing. We could argue that a "physical" source is always distributed so the point singularity disappears. This does of course lead to an unknown quantity $I_0$ for the integral over the omitted part. It will be finite for a physical source, but we don't know what it is without knowing details about the source. On the other hand, $I_0$ only depends on the details inside the radius $r_0$ of the omitted region $S$, not on the actual vertices of the triangle $ABC$.
Apart from that complication, we now just need to compute the integral of $1/r^3$ in the $xy$-plane over the triangle, excluding $S$. We do that,
as suggested in the question, by the divergence theorem. We define a vector field which is just the two-dimensional $E$-field of a charge density $1/r^3$, while region $S$ is made charge-free:
$$
{\bf F} = (F_x,F_y) = \big(\frac{x\,(r_0-r)}{r^3}, \frac{y\,(r_0-r)}{r^3}\big)
$$
for which we indeed have:
$$
{\bf \nabla}_{xy}\cdot{\bf F} = \frac{dF_x}{dx}+\frac{dF_y}{dy} = \frac{-1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
$$
so its two-dimensional divergence in the $xy$-plane is $-1/r^3$. This allows us to write the original
integral as a line integral along the boundary. By construction, ${\bf F}=0$ on the "inner boundary", the border of the omitted region at radius $r_0$. So we only get:
$$
\int\limits_\text{T\S} \! \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3} = 
\int\limits_\text{AB} \! \! d s \ {\bf n}_{AB}\cdot{\bf F} 
+\!\!\int\limits_\text{BC} \! \! d s \ {\bf n}_{BC}\cdot{\bf F} 
+\!\!\int\limits_\text{CA} \! \! d s \ {\bf n}_{CA}\cdot{\bf F} 
$$
where the normal vectors ${\bf n}_{AB}, {\bf n}_{BC}$, and ${\bf n}_{CA}$ are as in the drawing.
In this coordinate system only the
edge $AB$ can be easily computed, using the coordinates of $(1)$
$$
\int\limits_\text{AB} \! \! d s \ {\bf n}_{AB}\cdot{\bf F}
= \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \! \! d x \ F_y(x,h)
= \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \! \! d x \ \frac{h\,(r_0-(x^2+h^2)^{1/2})}{r_0(x^2+h^2)^{3/2}}
$$
So let's define:
$$
I_1(x_1,x_2,h) \equiv \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \! \! d x \ \frac{h\,r_0-h\,(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}{r_0 (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
= \left. \Big(\frac{x}{h\sqrt{x^2+h^2}} -\frac1{r_0} \arctan\frac x h
\Big)\ \right|_{\ \large x_1}^{\ \large x_2}
$$
We now observe that the parameters $x_1,x_2, h$ of Eq. $(1)$ are in fact related to the
points $A,B$ and $C$ in original coordinates by dot and cross products:
$$\begin{align}
h(\vec A,\vec B,\vec C) &= \frac{|(\vec C-\vec A) \times (\vec B-\vec A)|}{3\,|\vec B-\vec A|} \\[10pt]
x_1(\vec A,\vec B,\vec C) &= \frac{|(\vec A-\vec X) \cdot (\vec B-\vec A)|}{|\vec B-\vec A|} =
       \frac{|(2\vec A-\vec B-\vec C) \cdot (\vec B-\vec A)|}{3\,|\vec B-\vec A|}, \\[4pt]
& \qquad \ \ \text{where} \ \ \vec X  \ \text{is the barycenter, and likewise:}  \\[10pt]
x_2(\vec A,\vec B,\vec C) &= \frac{|(2\vec B-\vec C-\vec A) \cdot (\vec B-\vec A)|}{3\,|\vec B-\vec A|}
\end{align}$$
This means that we can find the $x_1,x_2, h$ for other coordinate systems where edges $BC$
and $CA$ are easy to compute by just rotating the points $A,B$ and $C$ in these expressions. Using
the defined $I_1(x_1,x_2,h)$ this (finally) gives:
$$\begin{align}
\int_\text{T\S}   \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3} =&
 \ I_1\big(x_1({\small \vec A,\vec B,\vec C}),\, x_2({\small \vec A,\vec B,\vec C}),\, y\,({\small \vec A,\vec B,\vec C})\,  \big) +
\\[4pt]
+&\ I_1\big(x_1({\small \vec B,\vec C,\vec A}),\, x_2({\small \vec B,\vec C,\vec A}),\, y\,({\small \vec B,\vec C,\vec A})\,  \big)
\\[10pt]
+&\ I_1\big(x_1({\small \vec C,\vec A,\vec B}),\, x_2({\small \vec C,\vec A,\vec B}),\, y\,({\small \vec C,\vec A,\vec B})\,  \big)
\end{align}$$
Using this in Mathematica gives:
<<JavaGraphics`
Clear["Global`*"] 
r=Sqrt[x^2+y^2]; Fy = y(r0-r)/r0/r^3; FyPrim = Integrate[Fy, x] 
I1[x1_,x2_,h_] = (FyPrim/.x->x2)-(FyPrim/.x->x1) /. y->h 

N2[v_]=Sqrt[v.v]; AbsX[u_,v_]=Sqrt[(u.u)(v.v)-(u.v)^2]  (* Abs[u cross v] *)
x1[u_,v_,w_]=(2u-v-w).(v-u)/N2[v-u]/3
x2[u_,v_,w_]=(2v-u-w).(v-u)/N2[v-u]/3
h[u_,v_,w_]=AbsX[w-u,v-u]/N2[v-u]/3

Ifin[a_,b_,c_] = I1[x1[a,b,c],x2[a,b,c],h[a,b,c]] +
   I1[x1[b,c,a],x2[b,c,a],h[b,c,a]]+I1[x1[c,a,b],x2[c,a,b],h[c,a,b]]

(*  Let's try some values, we get -17.2235 for this example:  *)
Ifin[ {-3,1,1}, {2,1,2}, {1,-2,-1} ] /.r0->0.3

I checked it with Mathematica's numerical integration and it seems to be correct.

This detailed answer and demonstrated understanding in such a short time is extremely impressive. I have no further questions for now as I will need time to familiarize myself with the approach.

@Bulbasaur Thanks, the problem is really a fine example of how we can use interesting methods for deceivingly simple questions about this integral on the triangle! Actually, there is a clearer derivation of the result, which I added as a second answer.

While [answer 283846] is perhaps the most straightforward following the earlier discussions, and also does show the use of the divergence theorem, there is a shorter way.
Second method:
Since the integral over $1/r^3$ is convergent for $r\rightarrow\infty$, we can integrate over
the entire plane $P$ with the disk $S$ excluded. This region $P\backslash S$ gives a fairly trivial result and we then can use:
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_\text{T\S} \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3} &= 
\int\limits_\text{P\S} \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3} -
\int\limits_\text{P\T} \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3} =
\\[10pt]
=\int\limits_{\large r_0}^\infty \! 2\pi r \, d r \ \frac{-1}{r^3} &- \!
\int\limits_\text{P\T} \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3}
=\frac{-2\pi}{r_0} - \!
\int\limits_\text{P\T} \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
so the extra ingredient needed is the integral over $P\backslash T$, i.e. the entire plane outside the triangle $T$.
We once again use the coordinate system of the other answer, with $T$ positioned like this:

and the points $A,B$ and $C$ in the 2D plane given as $(x_1,h), (x_2,h)$ and $(-x_1-x_2,-2h)$.
The left and right edge of the triangle then have these $y$-dependent $x$-coordinates:
$$
x_\text{le} =  x_1+\frac{y-h}{3h}(2x_1+x_2) \\
x_\text{ri} =  x_2+\frac{y-h}{3h}(2x_2+x_1)
$$
so for the integral over the plane outside $T$ we can add four regions:
$$\begin{align}
&\underbrace{\int\limits_{h}^\infty \! d y \!\! \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \!\! d x\, \frac{-1}{r^3}}
_{\text{above}}
 +
\underbrace{\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-2h} \!\! d y \!\! \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \!\! d x \, \frac{-1}{r^3}}
_{\text{below}}
 +
\underbrace{\int\limits_{-2h}^h \! d y \!\! \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\large x_\text{le}} \!\! d x\, \frac{-1}{r^3}}
_{\text{left}} +
\underbrace{\int\limits_{-2h}^h \! d y \!\! \int\limits_{\large x_{\text{ri}}}^{\infty} \!\! d x\, \frac{-1}{r^3}}
_{\text{right}} =
 \\[16pt]
=& \int\limits_{h}^\infty \!\!  d y  \frac{-2}{y^2}
 +\!\!
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-2h} \!\!\!   d y  \frac{-2}{y^2}
 +\!\!
\int\limits_{-2h}^h  \! dy\ \Big\{\, 
  \frac{-1}{x_\text{le}^2+y^2-x_\text{le}\sqrt{x_\text{le}^2 +y^2}} + 
  \frac{-1}{x_\text{ri}^2+y^2+x_\text{ri}\sqrt{x_\text{ri}^2+y^2}}
\Big\}
 \\[16pt]
=& \frac{-2}{h} + \frac{-1}{h} +
\frac{3(x_1-x_2) + 6 \sqrt{h^2+{x_1}^2}+3\sqrt{4
    h^2+({x_1}+{x_2})^2}}{2 h (x_1-x_2)}
\\[10pt]
&\qquad\qquad + \frac{3(x_1-x_2) + 6 \sqrt{h^2+{x_2}^2}+3\sqrt{4
     h^2+({x_1}+{x_2})^2}}{2 h (x_1-x_2)}
\\[16pt]
=&
\ \frac{3\,\big(\sqrt{h^2+{x_1}^2}+\sqrt{h^2+{x_2}^2}+\sqrt{4
    h^2+({x_1}+{x_2})^2}\,\big)}{h\ (x_1-x_2)}
\end{align}$$
So the integral from $(2)$ now becomes:
$$
\int\limits_\text{T\S} \! d^2 r \ \frac{-1}{r^3}  
=\frac{-2\pi}{r_0} +
\ \frac{3\,\big(\sqrt{h^2+{x_1}^2}+\sqrt{h^2+{x_2}^2}+\sqrt{4
    h^2+({x_1}+{x_2})^2}\,\big)}{h\ (x_2-x_1)}  \tag{3}
$$
Unlike in the other answer, we do not have to cycle over the three edges, this is already the complete answer! And of course
we can still express $x_1,x_2,$ and $h$ using the vertices in the original coordinate system as we did before. Checking this
in [this engine] gives:
Clear["Global`*"] 
r=Sqrt[x^2+y^2]
As = Assumptions->{Element[{y,xle,xri}, Reals], x1<0,x2>0,h>0,y!=0}
Iabove=Integrate[-1/r^3, {y,h,Infinity}, {x,-Infinity,Infinity}, As]
Ibelow=Integrate[-1/r^3, {y,-Infinity,-2h}, {x,-Infinity,Infinity}, As]
Ixle=Integrate[-1/r^3, {x,-Infinity,xle}, As]
Ixri=Integrate[-1/r^3, {x,xri,Infinity}, As]
  (*  Now integrate over y using the y-dependent xle and xri:  *)
xle=x1+(y-h)/(3h)(2x1+x2); xri=x2+(y-h)/(3h)(2x2+x1)
Ile=Integrate[Ixle, {y,-2h,h}, As]; Iri=Integrate[Ixri, {y,-2h,h}, As]
Itot = -2Pi/r0 - Simplify[ Iabove +Ibelow +Ile +Iri ]
  (* Result is:
                   2     2          2     2            2            2
  -2 Pi   3 (Sqrt[h  + x1 ] + Sqrt[h  + x2 ] + Sqrt[4 h  + (x1 + x2) ])
= ----- - -------------------------------------------------------------
   r0                              h (x1 - x2)
 
     Now relate x1, x2, h to the original vertices u, v, w:               *)
N2[v_]=Sqrt[v.v]; AbsX[u_,v_]=Sqrt[(u.u)(v.v)-(u.v)^2]  (* Abs[u cross v] *)
Ifin[r0_, u_,v_,w_] = Itot /. { x1->(2u-v-w).(v-u)/N2[v-u]/3,
                x2->(2v-u-w).(v-u)/N2[v-u]/3, h->AbsX[w-u,v-u]/N2[v-u]/3 }
  (*  Try the same values as before, again -17.2235 for this example!  *)
Ifin[ 0.3, {-3,1,1}, {2,1,2}, {1,-2,-1} ]

So we get the same answer as with the other method, but it is much clearer now from $(3)$ what the actual expression is!
